# why is devenv.exe scanning my disc at system startup

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2015, devenv

When I startup windows 10 and log-in, I find that devenv.exe is thrashing my disc for some minutes, even without running Visual Studio (2015 / 2017). Why is this, what is it doing and how can I prevent it? VS is not in my startup items.

Comment: VS install extension updates in background, that is why you see it. Start VS as admin and disable the automatic VS extension updates.

Comment: Hi Magicandre1982. Thank for your suggestion. However, updates were already switched off. In fact I needed to also switch off source control. My problem is now solved. Thanks.